# toggle class (JS) in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have an error, which is driving me insane. I tried so many ways already, but nothing seems to work, maybe you have a solution.

Our intranet has the IE-configuration, that it should run in IE7. Now there was a task, to create an accordeon-like effect for some of our content-sites.

**my HTML looks like this (just a short summary)**

```
<button class="accordion">Wie erfolgt die Auswertung?</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p><span style="font-size: 10pt; line-height: 115%">Jede Einheit, für die ausreichend ausgefüllte Fragebögen vorliegen, wird ausgewertet. Darüber hinaus fließen die Ergebnisse in die Auswertung der nächst höheren Ebenen ein.</span></p>
    <p><span style="font-size: 10pt; line-height: 115%">Einheiten, bei denen das nicht der Fall ist, erhalten keine eigene Auswertung. Hier fließen die Antworten direkt in die nächsthöhere Ebene ein.</span></p>
</div>
```

**and my JS looks like this (same file)**

```
<script>
var acc = $(".accordion");

var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onClick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;        
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

It seems like the display and block class never changes. I tried so many workarounds already.

Instead of `acc[i].onClick()...` I tried the `addEventListener()`-function. It seems this is not supported in IE < 8.
Then I tried to use `attachEvent()` - still no effect.

I tried to add the following meta-data:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

No effect. I even tried to add a workaround like this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ie8/0.2.6/ie8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Also didn't help. I get no error-messages in the console anymore, but this isn't popping up either. When I inspect the dome, nothing changes at all.

Any ideas? It just hast to work in IE7 - Chrome would be a nice benefit, but not mandatory.

Comment: IE7 definitely did not support the `.classList` property.

Comment: weird, since it yielded errors for "getElementsByClassName()" and "addEventListener()" - but not for .classList. I can use Jquery 1.7.2 - can we do a workaround with that?

Comment: jQuery has class set manipulation tools so yes.

Answer (score 2):

[classList doesn't work in IE7](https://caniuse.com/#search=classlist), but you can use `className`.

To append the class name 'active':

```
element.className += ' active';
```

Ensure there is a space to avoid overwriting the previous class.

To remove the class name:

```
element.className = element.className.replace('active', '');
```

With repeated toggling you may run into double spaces in your class list, so keep it tidy by doing something like this:

```
element.className = element.className.replace(/  /g, ' ');
```